# error rebuilding the index using django-elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to a existing index in my local elastic search engine.
I am using django-elasticsearch-dsl  package. I followed this tutorial to do that. https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl

please note that,I already developed my django app[website] with mysql database. I have some unstructured text data indexed in elastic-search. I want to develop this 'advanced search'  HTML page for users querying data frpm elasticsearch.

I followed almost everything upto 
`python manage.py search_index --rebuild` but once I excute it it asked Are you `sure you want to delete the 'website_data_discovery' indexes? [n/Y]:` when I say `n` it will be aborted.
when I say `Y` it gives a lengthy error saying `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Table 'crdc.website_data_discovery' doesn't exist`

This is my file structure.

```
crdc
website 
         ->__pycache__
         ->  media
         ->migrations
         ->static
         ->templates
         ->__init__.py
         ->admin.py
         ->apps.py
         ->documnets.py
         ->forms.py
         ->models.py
         ->tests.py
         ->urls.py
         ->views.py
manage.py
```

This is my settings.py/crdc.

```
###more codes here
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'website.apps.WebsiteConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_elasticsearch_dsl',

]

ELASTICSEARCH_DSL={
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200'
    },
}
###more codes here
```

This is documents.py/website

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index
from .models import Data_Discovery

data_discovery = Index('website_data_discovery')
data_discovery.settings( number_of_shards = 5, number_of_replicas = 1,)

@data_discovery.doc_type
class Data_DiscoveryDocument(DocType):
    class Meta:
        model = Data_Discovery
        fields = ['extracted_text',  'source_type']
```

this is models.py/website

```
from django.db import models

class WebsiteRepository(models.Model):
 ##### mysql model 

class Documents(models.Model):
 #### mysql model

class Data_Deposite(models.Model):
#### mysql model


class Data_Discovery(models.Model):
## Elasticsearch model
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Do you guys think django-elasticsearch-dsl pkg does not support python 3.7. I just found out that in the below github tutorial, its is mentioned, it says "requirements = Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6". Iam using python 3.7. and it seems, I cant downgrade it either.

Comment: The error suggests that you have not applied migrations after defining your models. `manage.py makemigrations && manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hi yeah,I tried that also. But no luck . Besides, according to the tutorial, we do not have to do that. for my mysql tables, I have already did that.

Comment: Which version of django you are using?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, its Django 2.1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is late. But, I thought I should answer my own question, so that anyone face the same problem, can figure it out.

I created another App for Elastic search component.Yes, I created another App under the same project. And I followed this tutorial https://pypi.org/project/django-elasticsearch-dsl/
Then I called Elasticsearch view functions at views.py from the website App. It works perfectly now.

I am not a expert in Django or Elastic Search. So, I can not explain why it is not working as the previous attempt. I hope this helps to anyone who comes to this kind of situation.